# Mysql: which pizza prefer client

Tags: mysql, database

I have table with this data :

```
 1. John | seafood pizza 
 2. Mike | pepperoni pizza 
 3. Mike | pepperoni pizza
 4. John | original pizza 
 5. Mike | original pizza 
 6. John | seafood pizza
 7. John | pepperoni pizza
```

....

How can I write a query that give me result such this:

```
John | seafood pizza
Mike | pepperoni pizza
```

If client have same quantity for many pizzas, the result may be any pizza's name.

Comment: Why does John get a seafood pizza in the result as opposed to an original pizza or (the best option IMHO) a pepperoni pizza? Is there a quantity column to base the decision on that is not shown here?

Comment: Lets say quantity on each row is 1.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take it step by step

the following query will give you number of times each client ordered each kind of pizza

```
SELECT name, pizza, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM yourTable 
GROUP BY name, pizza
```

So how do we get the most often ordered pizza from that? We must first know, what is the highest number of pizza ordered by each client

```
SELECT name, MAX(cnt) AS cnt FROM (
  SELECT name, pizza, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
  FROM yourTable 
  GROUP BY name, pizza
) AS subquery GROUP BY name
```

then use this number to select actual pizza name

```
SELECT name, pizza, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM yourTable AS t
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT name, MAX(cnt) AS cnt FROM (
    SELECT name, pizza, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
    FROM yourTable 
    GROUP BY name, pizza
  ) AS subquery GROUP BY name
) AS sq
USING(name,cnt)
GROUP BY name, pizza
```

Comment: Unknown column 'cnt' in 'from clause'

Comment: @Jbsh - if you get an error from a substantial answer such as this, it is a good practice to see what causes the error and 'tinker' a bit. Answers here, whilst good, should be considered hints upon which you can base your solution. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with grouping the counts by user and pizza then using this as a datasource for a query which finds the groupwise maximum (using the max concat trick). It's not hard:

```
SELECT user, SUBSTRING(MAX(CONCAT(LPAD(freq, 6, '0'),pizza)),7)
FROM
(SELECT user, pizza, COUNT(*) AS freq
FROM user_likes
GROUP BY user, pizza) ilv
GROUP BY user
```

Comment: And if there will be 'mixfood pizza' in table ?

Comment: eh? That's just another string.

Answer (score -1):

Let's have a simple solution :
First of all, we have two columns,name and food.
You can list of favorite customer's food easily :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbltemp AS (
SELECT name, food, COUNT( * ) c
FROM food
GROUP BY name, food
);
```

Now we have all of foods by count.
Then you can order it by count descending :

```
SELECT *
FROM tbltemp
ORDER BY c DESC
```

Now you have a list that describes your customer's favorite.

UPDATE :

Instead of second query ,replace this one :

```
SELECT tbl1 . *
FROM (

SELECT name, food, COUNT( * ) c
FROM food
GROUP BY name, food
) AS tbl1, (

SELECT name, food, COUNT( * ) c
FROM food
GROUP BY name, food
) AS tbl2
WHERE tbl1.c = tbl2.c
AND tbl2.name = tbl1.name
AND tbl2.food = tbl1.food
AND tbl1.c = (
SELECT c
FROM tbltemp
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 1 )
```

This query result is your question goal.

Comment: read the question - Mike will appear in tbltemp twice - not just for his favourite.